# Read time from 6 byte binary

Tags: datetime, time, timer, binary, hex

I have a 6 Byte hex string which i need to convert into a time in seconds. The information i have:
First example:

> Hex: BA 2F 96 00 00 00
>
> translates to:
>
> Time: 2.4606544971 sec

Further examples:

> 1. Hex: 90 7D 03 03 00 00
>
>    Time: 12.6400995255 sec
> 2. Hex: E9 5E A5 18 04 00
>
>    Time: 4398.3398437500 sec
> 3. Hex: 05 3A 37 16 04 00
>
>    Time: 4388.1469726563 sec
> 4. Hex: 8A B8 39 13 04 00
>
>    Time: 4375.6049804688 sec

I have tried to get the information with classical float double or date and time conversions but i couldn't get to the given times since i don't know any 6 Byte structures of that type. How can i calculate from the hex values the given times?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: C ... it is little endian.